# How to add performance test to Bluemix DevOps pipeline?

Tags: ibm-cloud, devops

Is there any chance to add performance test stage to Bluemix delivery pipeline?

What are the tools that are supported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, the Delivery Pipeline service is quite flexible. You can install tools, interact with external APIs, etc., in each job.

There are some performance testing tool integrations described at [the IBM Bluemix Garage Method site](https://www.ibm.com/devops/method/category/tools).